# How do I rename "Data" (from \KwData{}) and "Result" (from \KwResult{}) in \begin{algorithm} to something else?

Tags: algorithms

Say I have the following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\KwData{my data}
\KwResult{my output}
my algorithm
\caption{my caption}
\end{algorithm}
```

It will produce something like this:

---

**Algorithm 1:** my caption
**Data**: my data
**Result**: my output
1 my algorithm

---

I want to rename 'Data' and 'Result' to something else.

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the labels either globally (in the document preamble) or locally (in the `algorithm` environment) using `\SetKwInput`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

% global change
\SetKwInput{KwData}{The data}
\SetKwInput{KwResult}{The result}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\KwData{my data}
\KwResult{my output}
my algorithm
\caption{my caption}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
% local change
\SetKwInput{KwData}{Abbott}
\SetKwInput{KwResult}{Costello}
\KwData{my data}
\KwResult{my output}
my algorithm
\caption{my caption}
\end{algorithm}

% the local change has been reverted

\begin{algorithm}
\KwData{my data}
\KwResult{my output}
my algorithm
\caption{my caption}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]